# s3cmd pipe mongodb 3.0.2 SASL auth failed

Tags: mongodb, pipe, s3cmd, sasl, mongoimport

Does anybody experience an issue with `s3cmd` and `mongoimport` after having upgraded to mongodb 3.0.2? I am receiving the SCRAM-SHA1 / SASL error but have no clue how I can fix this? The connection from and to s3 is still unaffected and working properly.

I was untill recently successfully using `s3cmd` to pipe the output from mongodb 2.6:

```
s3cmd get s3://filename - | mongoimport -d testdb -c testcollection
```

which is now returning:

> "Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL
>   authentication step: Authentication failed."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try using the --[authenticationDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--authenticationDatabase) parameter to direct the mongoimport tool to the database that holds the user’s credentials. Currently it fails to authenticate since it can't find the location of those credentials.

The full command should look something like this:

```
s3cmd get s3://filename - | mongoimport -d testdb -c testcollection -u <user_name> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This is all true to version 2.4 and up of the mongoimport tool, so make sure you have an updated version.